# MYSQL get closest match with multiple WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

In my database, I have a table with products and another table that has tags associated to each of te products.

When the user looks at a product's page, I want to show the most "related" (or closest) product to the one he's looking at.

So let's say the product is tagged with 5 different tags. I would like to get the prodcuts that have the same 5 tags and then the ones that have 4 of the same 5 tags, and then the ones that have 3 of the same 5 tags, etc...

To do this, I'm guessing I would have to create one or more MYSQL query but I don't even know where to start.

Matching the same 5 tags is easy, I can just use WHERE tag='?' AND tag='?'... but how can I get the other (4/5, 3/5, 2/5, 1/5)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers
Steven

---

EDITS

@Orbits: My tags are all on different rows... if not I could probably do a text match but this is the the case. A tag row consists of (id, tag, product_id)

@cusimar9: Different table, as stated in the post :P

@vbence: I believe it's as simple as possible.. here is is... but I don't have a connecting table

PRODUCTS :

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

TAGS :

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=116 ;
```

Comment: are all the tags in the same field? how are they delimited?

Comment: Or are the tags in a separate table??

Comment: Please copy-paste 3 pieses of `CREATE TABLE` queries, defining your tag, product, and the connecting table. (The product's detail fields can be omitted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string literals 'Tag1' and so has to be replaced with your tags of course.

```
SELECT products.id, COUNT(tags.id) AS match_level
FROM products
    LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.product_id = product.id
WHERE tags.type IN ('Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3', 'Tag4', 'Tag5')
GROUP BY products.id
ORDER BY match_level DESC
```

If you don't have an index like this already, add it to your `tags` table. Without indexes you are wasting resources. Big time.

```
CREATE INDEX multimatch ON tags (type, product_id);
```

Comment: ... `tags.type IN ('Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3')`

Comment: @vbence @Mark I guess the number of tags is variable and the 5 number was just an example.

Comment: @Clodoaldo It is also an example here, it can be changed ofc. I just used 5 because of the question.

Comment: @Htbaa Thanks, I changed it, it makes little difference though.

Comment: Little difference? It reads a hell lot better than endless OR statements.

Comment: @vbence What I mean is that my guess is that each product can have any number of tags so the query should be generic.

Comment: @Clodoaldo I guess the query will be put togather in PHP. Besides that I can not think of a more generic way.

Comment: @symcbean What? LEFT JOIN not trendy anyore? :P

Comment: @Htbaa Yes, I can not argue with that, but it requires an other syntactic element to know. OR is already known by everyone who touched a computer.

Comment: @ComputerArts I added a proposed INDEX for your table. I strongly encourage you to create it for this type of queries.

Comment: @vbece - only any any use for finding products with NO matching tags - and even then it's a very innefficient solution (its also very unnecessarily slow for matching tags)

Comment: @symcbean I don't think it's any more inefficient than your suggestion. But I will make som tests if I have the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.*
  FROM ( SELECT P.*,
                P.Tag LIKE '%a%' AS Tag1,
                P.Tag LIKE '%b%' AS Tag2,
                P.Tag LIKE '%c%' AS Tag3,
                P.Tag LIKE '%d%' AS Tag4,
                P.Tag LIKE '%e%' AS Tag5
           FROM `products` P
          WHERE P.Tag LIKE '%a%' 
             OR P.Tag LIKE '%b%' 
             OR P.Tag LIKE '%c%'
             OR P.Tag LIKE '%d%' 
             OR P.Tag LIKE '%e%'
       ) A
 ORDER BY A.Tag1+A.Tag2+A.Tag3+A.Tag4+A.Tag5 DESC
```

Comment: You'll have to restructure the query to join across your two tables - I posted this as a general prinmciple before you added your table details - but the principle should still work. Returning the P.Tag LIKE '%a%' AS Tag1 gives you a 0 or a 1 in the inner query, and the outer just adds those results up and displays them in descending order.

Comment: It may not necessarily be the cleanest method, but it was the first that came to mind, and it does work

Comment: Although ugly it looks like it will work. That is not the problem. But the real problems are first the like in the where will make the use of indexes impossible. The other is that it will get others tags beyond those between the %S.

Answer (score 1):

Simples:

```
SELECT related.id, count(*) as matches
FROM products related,
     tags rel_tags,
     tags this_tags
WHERE this_tags.product_id=$product_id_for_this_product
AND this_tags.type=rel_tags.type
AND rel_tags.product_id<>this_tags.product_id
AND rel_tags.product_id=related.id
GROUP BY related_id
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select products.id, count(*) as matches
from products 
inner join tags on products.id = tags.product_id
inner join (
    select t.id
    from products p
    inner join tags t on p.id = t.product_id
    where p.id = $product_id
) product_tags on tags.id = product_tags.id
group by products.id
order by products.id desc
```